# Error while ignoring null query parameters - Spring JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA in my application to fetch certain records from the DB. Now, one of the query parameters that I am passing can be null in certain criteria. So I have designed the query in such a way that if the query parameter is not null, then the query parameter is used for extraction otherwise it is ignored.

**Query**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM fulfilment_acknowledgement WHERE entity_id = :entityId " +
            "and item_id = :itemId " +
            "and (fulfilment_id is null OR :fulfilmentId is null OR fulfilment_id = :fulfilmentId) " +
            "and type = :type", nativeQuery = true)
    FulfilmentAcknowledgement findFulfilmentAcknowledgement(@Param(value = "entityId") String entityId, @Param(value = "itemId") String itemId,
                                                            @Param(value = "fulfilmentId") Long fulfilmentId, @Param(value = "type") String type);
```

**NOTE:** *The type of fulfilment_id in the table fulfilment_acknowledgement is `int8`. It is a Postgres RDS.*

Now, if I encounter a scenario where the `fulfilmentId` is actually blank, I am getting the below error:

```
2022-06-23 15:31:56,997 89645 [boundedElastic-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - SELECT * FROM fulfilment_acknowledgement WHERE entity_id = ? and item_id = ? and (fulfilment_id is null OR ? is null OR fulfilment_id = ?) and type = ?
2022-06-23 15:31:57,154 89802 [boundedElastic-5] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
Exception while creating Fulfilment Acknowledgement: [could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have a solution in mind where I can update the `fulfilmentId` to a default value like -1 if it is null, but I need to understand why is it failing? What am I missing here?

Comment: I am guessing the actual problem is this: "Spring data repository sends null as bytea to PostgreSQL database" [http://www.javawenti.com/?post=39309].
I am guessing that, in this case, the solution would be to set it to a default value that can never occur. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar issue for a native query, which find records with matching column values. When the value for any parameter is null, hibernate uses the wrong type throws casting exceptions. After spending some time I found that in such cases need to use Hibernate's `TypedParameterValue`

So in your case `@Param(value = "fulfilmentId") Long fulfilmentId` would be
`@Param(value = "fulfilmentId") TypedParameterValue fulfilmentId`

Also from the service you need to convert your parameter accordingly from `Long` to `TypedParameterValue` as below:

`TypedParameterValue fulfilmentIdParam = new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.LONG, fulfilmentId);`

Comment: I am not using hibernate. i am only using Spring JPA.

Comment: @GurucharanSharma In that case which ORM you are using?